# Apply conditional on two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have this dataframe:

[image]

I want to create a ZIP column which will get the value of ZIP_y when ZIP_x is NaN and the value of ZIP_x when ZIP_x is not NaN.

I tried this code:

```
dm["ZIP"]=numpy.where(dm["ZIP_x"] is numpy.nan, dm["ZIP_y"],dm["ZIP_x"])
```

But that gave me this output:

[image]

As you can see, the ZIP column seems to be getting the values of ZIP_x in each of its cells.

Do you know how to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

`dm["ZIP"]=numpy.where(dm["ZIP_x"].isnull(), dm["ZIP_y"],dm["ZIP_x"])`

You can't use `is` or `==` for that matter to compare `NaN`s